# Fit an image proportionally inside a div - image should never be clipped

Tags: jquery, css, image, responsive-design

i've read a bunch of posts on fitting an image inside a div, but none solved my problem yet:

I have a responsive webdesign that sets the height of the container div to the browser window height, and then loads images into a flexslider. Most of the images will be larger than the browser viewport.

My problem is that I can make the photos fit the width correctly, but images never adjust the height properly. See http://stineheilmann.dk/portfolio/shoes/ (picture no. 3)

How do I ensure that the picture always stays inside the containing div, while maintaining the aspect ratio?

Comment: `img { width: 100%; height: auto; }` should work

Comment: Well, it doesn't, at least not in all browsers, as this doesn't resolve the clipping issues I have.

Answer (score 2):

Are there any browser restriction? Are you looking for something like [this demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/gu4wvptx/0)?

CSS

```
.frame{width:300px;height:300px;padding: 2px; border:1px solid #ccc;margin:5px;}
.frame img{max-width:100%;max-height:100%;}
```

HTML would be something like

```
<div class="frame">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7251/8165766003_0e57a95b55.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7251/8165766003_0e57a95b55.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Update: I have updated the demo with three images of different aspect ratios, that fit in the div without getting skewed or overflow out of the div.

Comment: I can't see your update.

So, in order for this to work, the containing div needs to have fixed width and height? I'll just edit the height and width using jQuery then, if necessary.

Comment: It works in Chrome, but not all other browsers.. I've updated the code on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this CSS to the following selector:

```
.flexslider .slides img {
    height:100%;
    ....
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't work in FF, and distorts the proportions of the images under certain conditions.